# Can I connect 3 display to a mid 2012 MBP retina?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I have a mid 2012 Retina display MBP, currently connected to 2 external displays.

Specs:

[image]

And these are the 2 current monitors, both FULL HD:
[image]
[image]

One of them is connected directly with native HDMI port and with the other one Im using an HDMI apple MiniDisplay Port adapter.

Im worried cause just bought another FULL HD 23" inches monitor and would like to use it as a third monitor, so I have 4 screens in total (I normally use MBP opened)

So what do you think? Can my Mac handle this? I bought a couple of Belkin HDMI to MiniDisplay port cables so I get rid of adapters.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the your MacBook Pro is able to handle three externals displays as you require. You'll need to connect one via the HDMI port, and the two others via the Thunderbolt (mini DisplayPort) ports.

Comment: Can this lead to excessive heat, as reported by a user in the "Third External Display Experiments" paragraph at the link below? Thanks https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-how-to-manually-switch-graphics.html

Comment: No, it cannot lead to excessive heat as in “this might damage something”. It can lead to increased fan noise however.